# Auto bucket separation in aggregate query in Mongo 3.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have data in a collection 'Test' with following entries like,

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("588b65f1e9a1e01dfc55a5ff"), 
 "SALES_AMOUNT" : 4500
},
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("588b65f1e9a1e01dfct5a5ff"), 
 "SALES_AMOUNT" : 500
}
```

and so on.

I want to equally separate into 10 buckets.
Eg :

If my total entries has 50, then it should be like,

> first_bucket : First 5 entries from `test` collection second_bucket :
>   Next 5 entries from `test` collection .....
>
> ....
>
> tenth_bucket : Last 5 entries from `test` collection.

Suppose, If total entries count has 101, then it should be like

> first_bucket : First 10 entries from `test` collection second_bucket :
>   Next 10 entries from `test` collection .....
>
> ....
>
> tenth_bucket : Last 11 entries from `test` collection.(Because 1
>   additional entry is there).

`$bucket` & `$bucketAuto` is in mongo 3.4.. But I use mongo 3.2.

Comment: All `$bucket` really does is implement `$switch` in a specific way. And `$switch` is really just syntactic sugar for `$cond` without nesting conditions in `else` arguments. `$cond` has been around as long as the aggregation framework has been, so It's always been possible.

Comment: @NeilLunn Can you pls tell how to proceed? I couldn't find `$swtich` in 3.2

Comment: That's why I just pointed to you to `$cond`. It's a ternary operator `if..then..else`. It should be pretty easy to work out.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes.. can you pl give some small snippet?

Comment: If you want "set counts" then you are better off actually sequencing "skip" and "limit" operations, if not simply slicing the results in code for such small numbers. "Buckets" would usually be done on something akin to "values within a range" and would therefore typically result in different counts/sizes. So it's less of an aggregation operation and more of either a query or post processing option. Depending on the overall size of results.